# Set liquid Variable value on click

Tags: javascript, jquery, liquid

How do I set a variable value with liquid onclick?

```
<a href="#" onclick="{% assign sortOrder = 'Alphabetical' %}">Sort by name</a>
<a href="#" onclick="{% assign sortOrder = 'Price' %}">Sort by price</a>
```

What I am trying to do is a basic sort product list, once you click in the selected option page will refresh with the new sorting order.

Answer (score 1):

You can not change Liquid variables or run Liquid code after the page has loaded.

To accomplish what you are trying to do, you can pass the information to Liquid through query parameters on the page url.

```html
<a href="pagename?sortOrder=Alphabetical">Sort by name</a>
<a href="pagename?sortOrder=Price">Sort by price</a>
```

The method to read the query parameters back will depend on which implementation of Liquid you are using.